# Angular 2+ consecutive route params; the last one componentless

Tags: angular, angular4-router

Here I have a route path followed by two route parameters, the route looks like `section/sectionId/dashboardId`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'section/:sectionId',
    component: SectionComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':dashboardId',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

What I need is to add a third parameter to this that is componentless. I need to use it for an ID as a parameter I can pass to one of my components. So I tried this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'section/:sectionId',
    component: SectionComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':dashboardId',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':dashboardParam',
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

I got a promise rejection that said "One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren".

So I add `redirectTo: ':dashboardId'` to the `:dashboardParam` child route, and I get "Cannot redirect to ':dashboardId'. Cannot find ':dashboardId'."

How can I add this third parameter without getting the errors?

Comment: why dont you have two routes to the same component ?

Comment: Wait, wouldn't that mean I would need a router-outlet in my DashboardComponent that would load another DashboardComponent?

Comment: why will it load another Dashboard component you will be doing your routing from within the Dashboard Component Right  ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can't write a route without the corresponding component to go or redirect. You can write like this

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'section/:sectionId',
    component: SectionComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':dashboardId/:dashboardParam',
        component: DashboardComponent    
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

and in the component check if `dashboardParam` parameter was passed to the component or not via

```
constructor(params: RouteParams) {
    var dashboardParam= params.get("dashboardParam");

    if (dashboardParam) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. The one thing I didn't mention was that I need this to function with or without the last parameter. So, using your example, I added a second child route to the same component without the dashboardParam. It works!

Comment: Can you think of any way to accomplish what I mentioned in my last comment without causing the DashboardComponent to be re-instantiated when switching between the the routes :dashboardId/:dashboardParam and :dashboardId?

Comment: Switching between routes will always instantiate a new component

Comment: Ok. But I still need make sure there isn't some way to accomplish this. Like not adding the additional route, but letting router know to still use the :dashboardId/:dashboardParam route even when the parameter isn't present. Or for now I suppose I can designate a default param to pass when the info isn't available.

Comment: Wondering is matcher might help: https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher. I'll have to come back to this later.